# setOnClickListener dynamically

Tags: android, button, listener, onclicklistener

I create different buttons dynamically like this:

```
for (int toShow = 1; toShow <= nShips; toShow++)
    {
        btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setBackgroundResource(shipDrawable.get(ima));
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);
        row[pos].addView(btn);
        btn.setId(shipId.get(ima));
        if (row[pos].getChildCount() == 3) pos++;
        ima++;
    }
```

I need to know the identity of each button because each other has different actions. Then, I try to set `onClickListener` like this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View btn) {
            switch(btn.getId()){
                case 1000: System.out.println("FIRST");
                break;

                case 1004: System.out.println("FOURTH");
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't work. It seems that the `onClickListener` only affects the last item was created. If I create four buttons, only the fourth will has an `onClickListener`.

How can I get my click listeners to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View btn) {
                switch(btn.getId()){
                    case 1000: System.out.println("FIRST");
                    break;

                    case 1004: System.out.println("FOURTH");
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

for (int toShow = 1; toShow <= nShips; toShow++) {
        btn = new Button(this);

        // Set the click listener to all your buttons
        btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

        btn.setBackgroundResource(shipDrawable.get(ima));
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);
        row[pos].addView(btn);
        btn.setId(shipId.get(ima));
        if (row[pos].getChildCount() == 3) pos++;
        ima++;
    }
```

Cheers,
Yuvi

Comment: This reply is very similar as Hiral's one. He posted first, so the 'Accepted Answer' goes to him. Sorry

Comment: @KrLx_roller that's fine. Although I just looked at the post times and I actually posted the answer before him..:) But whatever, I'm glad you solved your issues.

Answer (score 5):

You can do like:

```
OnClickListener clicks=new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            switch(v.getId())
            {
                case 1000: System.out.println("FIRST");
                break;

                case 1004: System.out.println("FOURTH");
                break; 
            }       
    }
};
for (int toShow = 1; toShow <= nShips; toShow++)
{
        btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setBackgroundResource(shipDrawable.get(ima));
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);
        row[pos].addView(btn);
        btn.setId(shipId.get(ima));
        btn.setOnClickListener(clicks);
        if (row[pos].getChildCount() == 3) pos++;
        ima++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After the end of the `for` loop, `btn` refers to the last button created, not all of them. Each time you do `btn = new Button(...)` you lose the previous value of the `btn`.

Since you're setting the click listener outside the `for` loop, only the last button gets that handler. For all buttons to work, you need to set the listener **inside** the for loop.

And in such cases, instead of putting a `switch` in one function and set the listener of all objects to that function, you usually create a general function and set the click listener of each object to a delegate around that function that passes extra arguments to the general function to determine what should be done.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I supposed that my error was that one, but I was not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
                  for (Answer a : q.getAnswers()) {
                        final CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
                        cb.setId(Integer.valueOf(a.getId()));
                        cb.setText(a.getValue());
                        cb.setTextColor(fontColor);
                        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                if(isChecked){
                                    inviCheckox.append("-"+String.valueOf(buttonView.getId()));
                                }

                        });
                        lCheckList.addView(cb);
                    }
```

I have tried with the code like this and it's working ( API Lv 10).

I can init the new View inside of the loop (final) and just add new listener to it